# Подсветка найденной улицы через geocode в yandex maps api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите как подсветить найденную улицу полученную из ymaps.geocode() на примере обычного поиска в Яндекс.Картах ( [https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?from=tabbar&ll=37.606026%2C55.762365&mode=search&sll=37.608186%2C55.759183&sspn=0.024008%2C0.013482&text=Москва%20Тверская&z=15.6](https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?from=tabbar&ll=37.606026%2C55.762365&mode=search&sll=37.608186%2C55.759183&sspn=0.024008%2C0.013482&text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F&z=15.6) )

Answer (score 1):

Ответ API Геокодера не содержит геометрию найденного объекта, поэтому подсветить его как на Яндекс.Картах не получится - нужно из какого-то стороннего источника, например, собственной базы, брать форму улицы.